# Leaking Markup in RICO live grid

Tags: ajax

I am using the RICO live grid ajax framework to create forms on a LAMP site.

I have several live grid tables with parent/child relationships. When the data is presented in a child table it is leaking markup.  It looks like this

```
Tomato and Shellfish Soup<span class="ricoLookup">71</span>
```

where '71' is the key and 'Tomato and Shellfish Soup' is the label when I should just see 'Tomato and Shellfish Soup'.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of Rico 2 - available in the [svn repository for the openrico project on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openrico/files/openrico/) fixes this issue.